# Hot to split requests in many rows in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Code one

```
import requests

url = "http://store.place.com.br/api/oms/pvt/orders"

headers = {

    'accept': "application/json",
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'x-vtex-api-apptoken': "{{VTEX-API-TOKEN}}",
    'x-vtex-api-appkey': "{{VTEX-API-KEY}}"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

## Code two

```
url = "http://store.place.com.br/api/oms/pvt/orders/oderId"

headers = {

    'accept': "application/json",
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'x-vtex-api-apptoken': "{{VTEX-API-TOKEN}}",
    'x-vtex-api-appkey': "{{VTEX-API-KEY}}"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

My results are:

{"list":[{"orderId":"BWW-Lojas_Americanas-265033423001", ...
{"orderId":"BWW-Lojas_Americanas-265032819901","sequence":"506927","market

How can I split each list in many rows? After that, I want to save them in different files.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the response as `JSON` using `requests.request(...).json()`. Then, you can process each order in the list.

Here's an example:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()

for order in response['list']:
    # Process each order
    # ...
```